# Identify consecutive integers from a list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following lists and I'd like to get the consecutive integers from all the list.

```
list = [[3, 10, 15, 88],
[4, 11, 30],
[1, 6, 12, 50, 74]]
```

It should return `[10, 11, 12]`.

If there are more than one consecutive list like

```
list = [[3, 10, 15, 88],
[4, 11, 30],
[5, 6, 12, 50, 74]]
```

It should return both `[3,4,5]` and `[10,11,12]`.

I'd like to know the most efficient solution. Thank you.

Comment: can the consecutive elements be in the same list or it is always in different lists?

Comment: Hi @Epsi95 it's always in different lists. Thanks

Comment: why not `[3,4,5,6], ...` for `[[3, 10, 15, 88],
[4, 11, 30],
[5, 6, 12, 50, 74]]`

Comment: Yes just about to ask

Comment: Also why not `[3,4]` in the first list

Comment: @PatrickArtner each from consecutive  list

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [[3, 10, 15, 88], 
    [4, 11, 30], 
    [5, 6, 12, 50, 74]]  

result = [[elem-1,elem,elem+1] for elem in l[1] if (elem+1) in l[2] and (elem-1) in l[0] ]

[[3, 4, 5], [10, 11, 12]]
```

`for elem in l[1]` : we are going to iterate over middle list and check if `elem+1`in the next list and `elem-1` in previous list

Comment: Nice solution, but you are also effectively doing `product(*l)` that is `O(l*m*n)` in worst case

Comment: I ran the time it on both the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in just one line using `product`:

```
from itertools import product  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
l = [[3, 10, 15, 88], 
    [4, 11, 30], 
    [5, 6, 12, 50, 74]]  

result = [[i,j,k] for i,j,k in product(*l) if k==j+1 and j==i+1]
```

The result will be:

```
In [7]: result                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[7]: [[3, 4, 5], [10, 11, 12]]
```

> Note that: Do not use `list` as a variable name. it is predefined in python and you will override its main functionality.

Comment: you are creating unnecessary extra list items with `product`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this to get the required answer

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = [ 1,4,5,6,10,15,16,17,18,22,25,26,27,28]
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i, x): i-x):
   print map(itemgetter(1), g)

Result:
[1]
[4, 5, 6]
[10]
[15, 16, 17, 18]
[22]
[25, 26, 27, 28]
```

Comment: Mind adding an explanation of your code?

Comment: I have picked this piece of code from the official documentation. Here's the link https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

with simple reasoning

```py
l = [[3, 10, 15, 88],
[4, 11, 30],
[5, 6, 12, 50, 74]]

l2 = [(index,j) for index,i in enumerate(l) for j in i] # flattening the list
l2 = sorted(l2, key= lambda x: x[1]) # sorting the list
# the sorted list has the below structure (sublist_number, item)

output = []
current_group = []
temp = []

for i in l2:
    if(len(temp) == 0):
        temp.append(i[1])
        current_group.append(i[0])
    else:
        if(i[1] - temp[-1] != 1): # that means not consecutive
            if(len(temp) == 3):
                output.append(temp.copy())
            temp.clear()
            current_group.clear()
            temp.append(i[1])
            current_group.append(i[0])
        else:
            if(i[0] not in current_group):
                temp.append(i[1])
                current_group.append(i[0])

print(output)
```

```
[[3, 4, 5], [10, 11, 12]]
```